# Azure Service Bus - Data Transmission Issue

Tags: c#, java, azure

I'm working on a project where we would like to send messages via an Azure Service Bus (Topic).  In this instance, I've setup a C# Console app and a Java app that sends and receives messages between them.

When sending a message from C#, I get a strangely formatted string within Java containing "schema.microsoft.com/2003/10/serialisation".  Changing the message content type makes no difference.

When sending data from Java to C# I get an exception.

**Send/Receive Data - C#**

```
private static void SendMessages()
    {
        topicClient = TopicClient.Create(TopicName);

        List<BrokeredMessage> messageList = new List<BrokeredMessage>();
        messageList.Add(CreateSampleMessage("1", "Test"));

        Console.WriteLine("\nSending messages to topic...");

        foreach (BrokeredMessage message in messageList)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    topicClient.Send(message);
                }
                catch (MessagingException e)
                {
                    if (!e.IsTransient)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        throw;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        HandleTransientErrors(e);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message sent: Id = {0}, Body = {1}", message.MessageId, message.GetBody<string>()));
                break;
            }
        }
        topicClient.Close();
    }

    private static BrokeredMessage CreateSampleMessage(string messageId, string messageBody)
    {
        BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage(messageBody);
        message.MessageId = messageId;
        return message;
    }
```

**C# Stacktrace**

***{"There was an error deserializing the object of type System.String. Unexpected end of file. Following elements are not closed: ."}***

```
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.DataContractBinarySerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.DataContractBinarySerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.GetBody[T](XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.GetBody[T]()
   at Microsoft.Samples.MessagingWithTopics.program.ReceiveMessages() in d:\Downloads\Getting Started  Messaging With Topics (1)\C#\MessagingWithTopics\program.cs:line 127
   at Microsoft.Samples.MessagingWithTopics.program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Downloads\Getting Started  Messaging With Topics (1)\C#\MessagingWithTopics\program.cs:line 39
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

a) You may not use AMQP from .NET. Only then you get AMQP encoding. Append TransportType=Amqp to connection string. And then use Apache Proton-J's JMS provider.

b) If you use HTTP from Java, try constructing the message either over a self-serialized stream (Stream parameterized constructor) or using for instance the DataContractSerializer explicity with the (object, XmlObjectSerializer) parameterized constructor. That will give you an XML Test payload. By default we use the NetDataContractSerializer which yields a compact encoding but is .NET only.

Comment: Is there any documentation on using Proton-J's JMS with Azure and Java?  Even following MSDN tutorials I still encounter errors, such as not even finding the classes from the libraries I've imported.